# This program stops working while execution . i made this program in codeblocks

Tags: c++

Why does this program stops working with a message which says process returned -1073741819 on codeblocks ?
All other programs are working on code blocks except for this one.
This is my uncompleted project for my college assingment.

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<vector>
    #include<math.h>
    #include<cstdlib>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        cout<<"\tThis is a C++ program to implement Quine-McCluskey logic to minimize a given Boolean function"<<endl;
        unsigned int nv,nmin,roll,i;
        vector<int> minterms;
        cout<<"Enter your roll number    ";
        cin>>roll;
        srand(roll);
        cout<<endl<<"Enter the number of variables(1-10)";
        cin>>nv;
        if(nv<1||nv>10)
        {
            cout<<endl<<"Invalid number of variables";
            exit(0);
        }
        cout<<endl<<"Enter the number of min-terms(1-"<<pow(2,nv)<<")   ";
        cin>>nmin;
        if(nmin<1||nmin>pow(2,nv))
        {
            cout<<"Invalid number of min-terms(1-"<<pow(2,nv)<<")";
            exit(0);
        }/*it stops here*/
        for(i=0;i<nmin;i++)
        {
            minterms[i]=rand()%int(pow(2,nv));
        }
        cout<<endl<<"The randomly generated min-terms are ";
        for(i=0;i<nmin;i++)
        {
            cout<<minterms[i]<<"  ";
        }

    }
```

Comment: You haven't set the size of vector and you go out of bound when setting
minterms[i]. You need to resize it beforehand. For example like that : minterms.resize(nmin);

Comment: What output do you expect for what input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not allocating any space in the `minterms` vector. Instead of assigning to `minterms[i]`, pass the values to `minterms.push_back()`.

Comment: what if i declare the vector as vector<int> minterms(nmin)

Comment: `nmin` is not yet set to any reasonable value.

Comment: @AbhishekKaushik As this answer says. Change `minterms[i]=rand()%int(pow(2,nv));` to `minterms.push_back(rand()%int(pow(2,nv)));`

Comment: should i do that in the loop or otherwise

Comment: Abhishek Declaring the vector to have a size like that would also work, but as Arda says, you'd also need to move the declaration of the vector to after `nmin` is assigned and tested to be valid; so, just before the loop that assigns the values.